# Are Pepin's deals ever "bad"?

Tags: happy-street

Frequently Pepin will offer to buy things from me.  The game clearly displays that he is offering me a price better than "market" though I don't really know where I can sell things other than to him.  Often times he offers flooz too, which seems very hard to come by.  Since there are so many items, and I sometimes don't really know their full worth yet - does Pepin ever offer me deals that are "bad" which I should not take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he offers Flooz, I take it every time. The only downside to accepting every deal he makes is if you are working to complete a quest and have harvested just enough resources and spent hours/days crafting an item for your villagers, it's painful to have to start that over for a few coins.

Comment: Thanks - I feel better accepting his deals now, knowing he's not ripping me off.  Considering the bird poop mini game I thought bad deals might be a potential.

Comment: Hey, what's wrong with clicking on a bird for his poop? Never mind, I just re-read that. You're right.